Django Database Routers "allow_migrate_model" throws the following: "TypeError: allow_migrate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app_label'"
the "allow_migrate_model" function within my database routers keeps throw the following error when I try to run python manage.py makemigrations:

...
File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 262, in allow_migrate
    allow = method(db, app_label, **hints)
TypeError: allow_migrate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app_label'


My Routers look like this (routers.py):
class BaseRouter:
    route_app_labels = {}

    db_name = ""

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints) -> Union[str, None]:
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return self.db_name
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints) -> Union[str, None]:
        if model._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return self.db_name
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints) -> Union[bool, None]:
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
            or obj2._meta.app_label in self.route_app_labels
        ):
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(
        self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints
    ) -> Union[bool, None]:
        if app_label in self.route_app_labels:
            return db == self.db_name
        return None


class DefaultRouter(BaseRouter):
    route_app_labels = {"auth", "contenttypes", "sessions", "admin", "myapp"}
    db_name = "default"


class LibraryRouter(BaseRouter):
    """ separate router for backend stuff """
    route_app_labels = {"library"}
    db_name = "library"

In settings.py
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    myproject.routers.DefaultRouter,
    myproject.routers.LibraryRouter,
]

The above is basically a slightly modified version found on the Django Docs.
If I comment out the allow_migrate the makemigrations works, however, I would like to modify the allow_migrate further so that's not a convincing option rn.
Ah also for some reason if a rewrite it into a staticmethod (like mentioned here) it works. But then I lose my variables stored in self so also not optimal...
I'm on Django 4.2.14 and Python 3.9.10

It is not an instance: it targets it as a class, that is the problem.


Ah also for some reason if a rewrite it into a staticmethod.

You likely registered the router as:
# settings.py

# import of DefaultRouter and LibraryRouter

# …

DATABASE_ROUTERS = [DefaultRouter, LibraryRouter]
Then it is not an instance: it targets it as a class, that is the problem: the method(…) is called as BaseRouter.allow_migrate(db, app_label, **hints), not through an instance.
We can solve this by constructing the instances, like:
# settings.py

# import of DefaultRouter and LibraryRouter

# …

DATABASE_ROUTERS = [DefaultRouter(), LibraryRouter()]
Another option is to move the logic one level up: by making it a @classmethod [python-doc]:
class BaseRouter:
    route_app_labels = {}
    db_name = ''

    @classmethod
    def db_for_read(cls, model, **hints) -> Union[str, None]:
        if model._meta.app_label in cls.route_app_labels:
            return cls.db_name
        return None

    @classmethod
    def db_for_write(cls, model, **hints) -> Union[str, None]:
        if model._meta.app_label in cls.route_app_labels:
            return cls.db_name
        return None

    @classmethod
    def allow_relation(cls, obj1, obj2, **hints) -> Union[bool, None]:
        if (
            obj1._meta.app_label in cls.route_app_labels
            or obj2._meta.app_label in cls.route_app_labels
        ):
            return True
        return None

    @classmethod
    def allow_migrate(
        cls, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints
    ) -> Union[bool, None]:
        if app_label in cls.route_app_labels:
            return db == cls.db_name
        return None
The DATABASE_ROUTERS should actually work with a string, but I agree that is perhaps not the best way from a software design perspective: if you rename the class, it is possible that the string does not change, and so it refers to a non-existing item that does not per se raises an exception, but the way it was designed is:
# settings.py

# …

DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    'module_name.DefaultRouter',
    'module_name.LibraryRouter'
]

No, the class is actually instantiated internally by Django, see the code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/0e49a8c3bd9119795525d9f076f73740741479b7/django/db/utils.py#L211 (I am guessing their setting is such that it hits the else block there)

@AbdulAzizBarkat: yes, I think it was DATABASE_ROUTERS = [DefaultRouter] so as class reference.

Yah, thank you! That has done the trick, I just missed in the docs that they use the string nomenclature, but instantiating works just fine, so I will use it like that. Thanks!
